# Performing Count() and Avg() within a Case statement

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2014

I am using this CASE statement to show a total count of visits and average length of visit grouped by age groups:

```
    CASE WHEN AgeCalcSort = 0 AND  AgeCalcSort <= 1 then (
        Count(VisitID),
        AVG(DATEDIFF(dd,StartDate,EndDate ))
        )
    WHEN AgeCalcSort >= 2 AND  AgeCalcSort <= 17 then (
                Count(VisitID),
        AVG(DATEDIFF(dd,StartDate,EndDate ))
        )
    WHEN AgeCalcSort >= 18 AND  AgeCalcSort <= 64 then (
                Count(VisitID),
        AVG(DATEDIFF(dd,StartDate,EndDate ))
        )
    WHEN AgeCalcSort >= 65 then (
                Count(VisitID),
        AVG(DATEDIFF(dd,StartDate,EndDate ))
        )
    END,
```

The result should look like this:

```
Age 1 Count  Age 1 Avg LOS      Age 2 Count  Age 1 Avg LOS      Age 3 Count  Age 3 Avg LOS      Age 4 Count     Age 4 Avg LOS
5           5.3                 18          9.2                 20              12              0               0
```

Can anyone adivse what am I doing wrong, or a better way to achieve the end result?  Thanks In advance.

Comment: `AgeCalcSort = 0 AND  AgeCalcSort <= 1`? That's a long way to write `AgeCalcSort = 0`.

Comment: @baratier-erebusduhalm  @Baratier - Is `AgeCalcSort` of datatype `INT`?

Comment: @BhavinGosai, no, it's varchar type

Comment: @baratier-erebusduhalm @Baratier - Please try 2 solutions mentioned in my answer. additionally, can you have have value of `AgeCalcSort` as not whole number like `17.6` or `64.2`?

Comment: The AgeSort will always a whole number. The Averages will have decimals. And that is the problem I have now. when the average is 3.2 it  shows as 3.0, or when the avg is .067  then it shows just as 0.00. any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mentioned 2 points:

> **1) Can anyone adivse what am I doing wrong**

- You are using the `CASE` expression in your query incorrectly.
- You cannot have 2 columns returned when some condition is satisfied in `CASE` statement.
- As per **Microsoft documentation**, `CASE` evaluates a list of conditions and returns one of multiple possible result expressions.
- Check this Microsoft white paper for further study Ref. [URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql)

> **2) a better way to achieve the end result**

- There can be many ways to achieve this.
- Below is one of the simple way. try the query below:

  ```
  SELECT
      SUM(CASE WHEN AgeCalcSort = 0 AND AgeCalcSort <= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Age 1 Count], 
      AVG(CASE WHEN AgeCalcSort = 0 AND AgeCalcSort <= 1 THEN DATEDIFF(DAY,StartDate,EndDate) ELSE NULL END) [Age 1 Avg LOS]
      SUM(CASE WHEN AgeCalcSort = 2 AND AgeCalcSort <= 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Age 2 Count], 
      AVG(CASE WHEN AgeCalcSort = 2 AND AgeCalcSort <= 17 THEN DATEDIFF(DAY,StartDate,EndDate) ELSE NULL END) [Age 2 Avg LOS]
      SUM(CASE WHEN AgeCalcSort = 18 AND AgeCalcSort <= 64 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Age 3 Count], 
      AVG(CASE WHEN AgeCalcSort = 18 AND AgeCalcSort <= 64 THEN DATEDIFF(DAY,StartDate,EndDate) ELSE NULL END) [Age 3 Avg LOS]
      SUM(CASE WHEN AgeCalcSort >= 65 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Age 4 Count], 
      AVG(CASE WHEN AgeCalcSort >= 65 THEN DATEDIFF(DAY,StartDate,EndDate) ELSE NULL END) [Age 4 Avg LOS]
  FROM [YourTableName]
  ```

**Query explanation**

- I have achieved count by using `SUM`, if you look into any of count logic you will notice it says when it satisfies condition `1` else `0`. and that is summed later using `SUM`. So that all `1`'s ultimately gives count.
- for average you will notice that then condition is not satisfied I am using `NULL`, which is intentional, to avoid wrong math.
- for in TSQL query `AVG` of `(2,4,NULL)` is `3`, while `AVG` of `(2,4,0)` is `2`. so in your case `NULL` will help to avoid messing average value.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It helped me built the rest of the report.

Answer (score 1):

A `case expression` returns a single value, which you may then count or average.

It is not possible to produce multiple columns of output from a singe `case expression`. So, you need one case expression for each wanted column of output, like this:

```
select
      COUNT(CASE WHEN AgeCalcSort = 0  AND  AgeCalcSort <= 1 then VisitID end)
    , AVG(CASE WHEN   AgeCalcSort = 0  AND  AgeCalcSort <= 1 then DATEDIFF(dd,StartDate,EndDate ) end)
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN AgeCalcSort = 2  AND  AgeCalcSort <= 17 then VisitID end)
    , AVG(CASE WHEN   AgeCalcSort = 2  AND  AgeCalcSort <= 17 then DATEDIFF(dd,StartDate,EndDate ) end)
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN AgeCalcSort = 18 AND  AgeCalcSort <= 64 then VisitID end)
    , AVG(CASE WHEN   AgeCalcSort = 18 AND  AgeCalcSort <= 64 then DATEDIFF(dd,StartDate,EndDate ) end)
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN AgeCalcSort = 65 then VisitID end)
    , AVG(CASE WHEN   AgeCalcSort = 65 then DATEDIFF(dd,StartDate,EndDate ) end)
from ...
```

Notes:

- place each case expression inside the relevant aggregate function
- the `count()` function ignores NULLs so if the when conditions are not met the count will not increment
- whilst T-SQL documentation can sometimes use the term "case statement" technically that is incorrect; e.g. a complete select query is a "statement", and "expressions" evaluate to single values, hence the correct term is `case expression`